# Pass file as command line argument to Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am coding a Spark job in Scala and need to send some argument through command-line in JSON file format like the application name, master and some more variables.

```
./bin/spark-submit --name "My app" --master local[4] --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" myApp.jar
```

I need to send app name, master and all arguments in one JSON file like:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --properties-file  property.conf
```

Is that possible? How? Can anyone please explain with a simple example?

Comment: You can add those configuratons to `conf/spark-defaults.conf` in the form of k-v pairs separated by a space, and `spark-submit` will read it from there

Comment: I am using https://github.com/scopt/scopt which is really nice for parsing command line argument.

Comment: thanks philantrovert , default is good , but i need to override default configration using command line  right now i am using json string as argument but its little bit difficult so need to parse as file or object ,may be jar is good option but every time i change in configuration file than i need to change in jar to at this time i need to build jar every time ???

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--jars` option as follows:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars property.conf --class your.Class your.jar
```

The help page of `spark-submit` will yell you more:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --help

  --jars JARS Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
              and executor classpaths.
```

Despite the name, you can also use it to move around configuration files that you want to be in your driver and executors' classpath.